# CSS: How to get this overlay to extend 100% with scrolling?

Tags: html, css, overlay

Here is an example of the issue in question:

http://dev.madebysabotage.com/playground/overlay.html

You see there is a gray overlay over the entire page, but if you scroll down, the content below the initial loaded page doesn't have the overlay.

I have an `#overlay` div and it seems it doesn't keep the 100% height during scrolling, so trying to figure out how to pull that off.

Here's the full source:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
}

#overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
}

header,
section,
footer {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ff0;
}

section {
  min-height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<section>
  <p>Here's some sweet content</p>
</section>
<footer>
  <p>Here's my footer</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! For anyone else reading, the problem is fixed at the link above. To recreate it use Firebug or similar to remove `position:fixed;` from the overlay id :)

Comment: 3yrs later and I have a same problem :) +1 for question

Answer (score 178, accepted):

`position: fixed;` on the overlay.

Comment: You note that fixed positions is not supported in IE6. But considering the fact you are using rgba values, I guess you do not care about IE at all. :p

Comment: who does? ;) (we all should really) ha

Comment: Okay, now what about tablets and mobile devices?

Comment: 8yrs later - Add "overflow: hidden;" to body when overlay is opened to avoid double scroll bar in some browsers.

Comment: What if the overlay is not relative to the body, but for some child element which has scrolling?

Answer (score 10):

Change `#overlay` `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`

Answer (score 6):

This happens because the `#overlay` `position: absolute` is relative to the `<html>` and using it's dimensions, which is only the viewport height.

To make sure that the `#overlay` uses the dimensions of whole page, you could use `position: relative;` on the `<body>` (but you will need to remove the `min-height: 100%` and `height: 100%` on the `<body>` first because this makes it use the viewport size). The `#overlay` will then use the `<body>` dimensions and fill the entire page.