# Full Body Overlay With inner divs clickable

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an overlay to my page which is 100% in size. The problem is that the inner divs and buttons are not clickable anymore. Is there a way out of this?

I used the answer here to add the overlay: [CSS: How to get this overlay to extend 100% with scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648418/css-how-to-get-this-overlay-to-extend-100-with-scrolling)

What i'm trying to achieve is like the mask we add to a layer/group in photoshop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The overlay, being on a layer above that of the button container, is most likely intercepting pointer events. Disable them:

```
.overlay {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a little bit of JavaScript or JQuery

here is the html page with JQuery and CSS

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>
        tester
    </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
               $(".overlay").fadeIn();
               $(".popup").fadeIn();
            });

             $(".overlay").click(function(){
               $(".overlay").hide();
               $(".popup").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>


    <style>
        *
        {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: "helvetica ";
        }
        button
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 47%;
            height: 50px;
            border: none;
            top: 10%;
            width: 5%;
            border-radius: 10px/150px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            z-index: -2;
        }
        button:hover
        {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #212121;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .overlay
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 667px;
            background: black;
            z-index: 1000;
            opacity: 0.5;
            display: none;
        }

        .overlay:hover
        {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .popup
        {
            width: 50%;
            height: 350px;
            background: white;
            z-index: 1001;
            position: absolute;
            left: 25%;
            top: 25%;
            border-radius: 20px;
            padding:15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 36px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>
        Pop up
    </button>

    <div class="overlay">

    </div>
    <div class="popup">
        <p>AM A Pop Up</p>
        <input type="button" value="click me">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```